# Re-stream (forward) UDP-Live-Video-Stream (using winsock) reduce video quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, forwarding, sockets, udp

So, I used ffmpeg to stream the live webcam using UDP protocol to port 1111 :

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera" -f mpegts udp://localhost:1111
```

When I played it directly by ffplay from port 1111, everything worked properly:

```
ffplay udp://localhost:1111
```

I got the video quality like this :

[image]

So I think, I could write some winsock-codes to **listen to port 1111 & forward any UDP packet that it catches to port 2222**. Thus, I could simulate that I'm streaming to port 2222.
My code is something like this :

```
' // Please note that this is the simplified code - cause it worked
' // i've just post the key lines
Winsock1.Bind 1111
Winsock2.remotePort = 2222

WinSock1.GetData myPacket
Winsock2.SendData myPacket
```

Then I tried playing the stream from port 2222 using ffplay:

```
ffplay udp://localhost:2222
```

Well, I don't know why the video quality turned to this bad:

[image]

The point is that, I've sent the same UDP packets in the same order as the streaming-source. What could be wrong here?

---

PS: I've tried a similar experiment like above with TCP, but the end-result video quality was as good as direct streaming. So, could this be a problem of UDP ?

---

PS2 : I've tested the UDP packet loss & disorder by replacing the ffplay with a socket that listen to port 2222 & print out all the received packets. But the result is all 10,000+ packets were in correct order & nothing lost. What a crazy phenomenon?